# Given $X, Y$ non-empty sets, is there a surjective function between $X$ and the set $\{f:Y \rightarrow X: f \text{ is function}\}$?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I was wondering to use the inclusive function but that's if $A$ were a subset of $B$, also remark that $A$ and $B$ are any non empty sets so if I try to use function $g:X \rightarrow Y$ I think is kinda use what I want to prove.

Comment: Also I saw that if H:={f:Y->X:f is function} is subset of the power set of (YxX)

Comment: I don't get what you want to find.

Comment: A surjective function from X to H:={f:Y->X:f is function}

Comment: For any $y \in Y$, evaluation at $y$ is a surjective map from $X^Y$ to $X$.

Comment: so if there's a surjective map from X^Y to X then there exist an injective map from X to X^Y, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|H = \{f : Y \rightarrow  X: f \text{ is a function}\}| = |X|^{|Y|}$.

To have a surjective function from $X$ to $H$, you must have $|X| \ge |H|.$

In particular, if $X,Y$ are finite, then $|Y| = 0 \text{ or } |Y| = 1.$

Comment: If you know that $Y \ne \emptyset$, then you can only have $|Y| = 1$.

Comment: Yes, I see you're right also we have Y non-empty so... |Y|=1, thanks!

Comment: Note that this works fine if $X,Y$ are finite sets, otherwise one should be more careful.